# glGenBuffers and many OpenGL function EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Macbook Air

Tags: opengl, exc-bad-access

I have a weird problem that a lot of OpenGL functions failed with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my MacBook Air. A very simple function like glGenBuffers or glGetString(GL_VENDOR) would get this result. I run it in Xcode. And I get segmentation fault: 11 if I run in terminal.

A example code like this is failed:

```
#include<GLUT/glut.h>
#include<OpenGL/gl.h>
#include<OpenGL/glu.h>
#include<OpenGL/glext.h>

int main(){
    unsigned int test[3];
    glGenBuffers(3, test);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure whether this is a problem with my system or not. I am using the 2012 version of MacBook Air with OSX 10.8.2 .

Answer (score 3):

Where's your OpenGL context creation code? You need an valid, active OpenGL context so that you can access OpenGL at all. Also by including `glext.h` you declare `glGenBuffers` as a function pointer that must be initialized through the extension loading mechanism. Without initializing that pointer to the right OpenGL function, dereferencing it (= calling it) will cause a segfault.

In MacOS X you normally don't need `glext.h` because all the OpenGL functions actually supported by the available version of MacOS X are already present in the OS X Framework.

Using the extension mechanism makes sense if you want to support a wide range of MacOS X versions.